# Export Datagridview to existing Excel file C#

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, datagridview, export

i have a problem with my Software. I want to export a Datagridview to an existing excel File. My software imports a excel file to a datagridview and now i want to do changes to the gridview and then safe it back. I already tried a lot of options, but i want to add it into a existing file and the most tutorials are about how to export it into a new one. Could anybody help me with my problem? I also had the idea of exporting the gridview to a new one and copy after that, the sheet of the new one into the existing one. But same problem, i can´t find anything. I´m very new to this whole programming thing and just a learnee in my company. It would be very great if someone could help me! And sory if my english is bad, I live in Germany. Thank you:)

Comment: If you have code that reads an excel file and imports the data into a `DataGridView`, then It should not be that hard to figure out the reverse operation. You do not say how your `DataGridView` is populated, is the DataGridView data bound? How are you adding new items to the `DataGridView`? Do you want to add a NEW sheet to an existing workbook or add data to an existing worksheet that already contains data? How are you referencing Excel, Interop, EPPlus or some other third party library?

Comment: SO is not really a place where you are going to get this kind of help. Try something and if it doesn’t work as expected, post your code here and others can help.  You may want to view the following info on asking questions. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add in your reference (right click your project and choose CON reference and look for Microsoft Excel 15.0 obeject library)

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlworksheet = 
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
           
    xlworksheet.Application.Workbooks.Open(
        @"C:\Users\BLANKSOASHEET.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
           
    try
    {
       for(int i=1; i<DgvSOA.Columns.Count+1; i++)
       {
           worksheet.Cells[1,i] = datagridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
       }       

       for (int i = 0; i < datagridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < datagridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
           {
                xlworksheet.Cells[i + 13, j + 1] = datagridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will save to a specific Excel file in a specific location.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Int16 i, j;

            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"c:\csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```